# Console output Xcode Playground

Tags: xcode, macos, error-handling, console

I'm getting an error file from my xcode console. Console output Xcode Playground

> Unable to create symlink at /Users/petergoeren/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.HelloGreg-8245CB75-384D-4509-BADB-9FB6466D4C88/Data/Documents/Shared Playground Data due to error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “Shared Playground Data” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x7fb04850c500 {NSFilePath=/Users/petergoeren/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.HelloGreg-8245CB75-384D-4509-BADB-9FB6466D4C88/Data/Documents/Shared Playground Data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb04850bce0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"})
>   hello Greg

This seems that a file is trying to save to a file that is already there. After I delete the file, it works once to pull up the correct error free console then the error comes back. Anyone ever run into this problem and know a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issu after a recent update to beta 4. After reading the devcenter forums I created the folder “~/Documents/Shared Playground Data”.

The message still appears now and then but not that often.

/MiB